# JasperReports: How do beans map to the correct bands/elements?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Say I have multiple detail bands containing pie charts. Each pie chart's JRXML looks like:

```
<pieDataset>
    <keyExpression><![CDATA[$F{PieSlice}.label]]></keyExpression>
    <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{PieSlice}.value]]></valueExpression>
</pieDataset>
```

And then I use a `JRBeanArrayDataSource` to fill those pie charts:

```
public class PieSlice
{
    private String label;
    private Double value;

    public PieSlice()
    {
        this("", -1);
    }

    public PieSlice(String lbl, Double val)
    {
        setLabel(lbl);
        setValue(val);
    }

    public String getLabel()
    {
        return label;
    }

    public String getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
}

public class PieSliceFactory
{
    private static PieSlice[] slices = 
    {
        new PieSlice("Fizz", 75.0),
        new PieSlice("Buzz", 25.0);
    };

    public static PieSlice[] getSlices()
    {
        return ArrayList.asList(slices);
    }
}

JasperReport jasperReport = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperDesign, new JRBeanArrayDataSource(PieSliceFactory.getSlices()));
```

Then how do I specify which data from the bean array gets "routed" to the correct pie chart? What if I only want the "*Fizz*" pie slice to go to pie chart *X* inside detail band *A*, but I want the "*Buzz*" slice to fill pie chart *Y* inside detail band *B*?

Is there a way to use IDs in the expressions or `CDATA`? There has to be a way to make specify which bands/elements data gets mapped to. The expression `$F{ClassName}.property` just seems too generic.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your result set has 3 rows, then your detail band will repeat 3 times. If you put a pie chart in the detail band, then you'll get 3 pie charts.

Your code above uses misleading names because you'll have one `PieSlice` in each row. So those `PieSlices` can't really be pie slices. Well.. of course they CAN... but each pie will have a single slice. It won't be useful.

It sounds like you need to put the pie chart into the title or summary band. Then you'll have the full data set to work with. You can have each of the pie slice labels and values represented in the chart.

Comment: Thanks mdahlman - but this brings up 2 tangential questions. If I'm reading your answer correctly, it seems as though the number of detail bands is directly related to the number of records/beans provided by your JRDataSource. However in the JasperDesign API it seems that you can programmatic-ally add 1+ detail bands to your report. So my followup questions are: (1) is there always a 1:1 relation between data source beans and detail bands, and (2) what data (fields,params,etc.) do detail bands not have access to that other bands do? And thanks again for taking the time to respond!